# java.nio.file: Where is the Path interface actually implemented?

Tags: java, java-7, java.nio.file

Recently I was doing some coding using the java.nio.file package introduced in Java 7 and saw an example using Path like this:

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users");
```

Given that Path is an interface I was confused on how you could have a reference to it, however after some research I found out that a reference to an interface is allowed but it must point to a class that implements the interface.  Looking on from this I looked at the Paths class and saw that it didn't implement Path.  Looking at the source code the actual method Paths.get method is as follows:

```
public static Path get(String first, String... more) {
    return FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(first, more);
}
```

the method first returns an object of type FileSystem (from an abstract class I think) using what I believe is called a static factory method, but FileSystem also doesn't implement the interface.

My question is does anyone know/able to explain where the Path interface is actually implemented as I cannot seem to find where this occurs.

Comment: System.out.println(path.getClass());

Comment: If you use IDE like Eclipse, you can use *Show type hierarchy* feature. http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-6.htm

Comment: `getPath()` returns a reference to an object that implements `Path`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you look carefully you will notice that the method `getPath` from `FileSystem` object returns implementation of Path interface. By invoking `FileSystems.getDefault()` you will retrieve implementation of `FileSystem` interface which will depend on system. On Linux system you will get `LinuxFileSystem` object witch extends `UnixFileSystem` class.

You can look for example at `UnixFileSystem` class from openjdk which is implementation of `FileSystem` interface.

Here is the link with implementation of `getPath` method from [UnixFileSystem](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/nio/fs/UnixFileSystem.java#UnixFileSystem.getPath%28java.lang.String,java.lang.String%5B%5D%29), which will return instance of [UnixPath](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/nio/fs/UnixPath.java#UnixPath).

You must remember that `FileSystems.getDefault` return implementation dependent on the operating system. Furthermore source code of those classes isn't available in oracle jdk.

Comment: How to fix those missing source code in oracle jdk?

Comment: @iamprem:  I don't think you can.  Check out openjdk instead.

Answer (score 2):

**Inside NetBeans IDE**, you can view the implementation details of Paths class by doing the following:

- Step one:

  click your cursor on the line where you have written your Path code. An example Path would be:

Path p = Paths.get("someDir\someOtherDir");

- Step Two:

Click Debug | Step Into (F7)

It will bring up the implementation details of Paths